# C++ How should I interpret a function argument long(*pPointer)(OtherClass *const, long)?

Tags: c++

I can't make any sense of this syntax. What should be passed to the function? A pointer of type long, or a pointer to an instance of `OtherClass`? What is the meaning of `,long` in the end?

In the doxygen documentation this syntax resolves to:

```
long(*)(OtherClass *const, long)    pPointer,
```

I've tried to search for examples of this syntax, but it is difficult to search for braces and asterisks.

Comment: A function (pointer) that returns a `long` and taking 2 parameters of type `OtherClass *const` and `long`.

Comment: https://cdecl.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pointer to a function named `pPointer` (the naming is debatable here). Imagine this function somewhere in your code base:

```
long someFunction(OtherClass *const param1, long param2);
```

It can be passed to as the type in your question title as

```
passFct(someFunction);
```

where the receiving function might look like

```
void passFct(long (*pPointer) (OtherClass *const, long))
{
    /* ... */

    /* Actually call the function to with pPointer points: */
    pPointer(&otherClassInstance, 10l);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a pointer to a function that takes an argument of othertype and long and returns a long. The name of the function pointer is pPointer.